# How to pass events to a parent View, passing the child View that triggered the event?

Tags: ember.js

Consider a View that defines a list of objects:

```
App.ListView = Ember.View({
  items: 'App.FooController.content'

  itemClicked: function(item){

  }
)};
```

with the template:

```
<ul>
{{#each items}}
    {{#view App.ItemView itemBinding="this" tagName="li"}}
      <!-- ... -->
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

and the ItemView:

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({

  click: function(event){

    var item = this.get('item');

    // I want to call function itemClicked(item) of parentView
    // so that it handles the click event
  }
})
```

So basically my question is how do I pass events to parent views, especially in the case where the parent view is not known by the child view? I understand that you can get a property `foo` of a parentView with either `this.getPath('parentView').get('foo')` or `this.getPath('contentView').get('foo')`. But what about a function (in this case, `itemclicked()`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this.get('parentView').itemClicked(this.get('item'));` should do the trick.

Comment: I thought I test that, and it didn't work. I will make a jsFiddle to test it. I'm pretty sure `this.get('contentView').itemClicked(this.get('item'));` (for passing events to grand-parents) will not work.

Comment: @Zack It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomwhatmore/FGyrV/1/ unless of course I've misunderstood the question. Might be because you were using `getPath()` instead of just `get()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `{{action}}` helper, see: http://jsfiddle.net/smvv5/

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#view App.ListsView}}
        {{#each items}}
            {{#view App.ListView itemBinding="this" }}
                <li {{action "clicked" target="parentView" }} >{{item.text}}</li>
            {{/view}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/view}}
</script>​
```

JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Foo = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [Ember.Object.create({
        text: 'hello'
    }), Ember.Object.create({
        text: 'action'
    }), Ember.Object.create({
        text: 'world'
    })]
});
App.ListsView = Ember.View.extend({
    itemsBinding: 'App.Foo',
    clicked: function(view, event, ctx) {
        console.log(Ember.getPath(ctx, 'item.text'));
    }
});
App.ListView = Ember.View.extend({
});​
```

Comment: Does this actually work on the latest version of Ember? The click event doesn't ever seem to pass any parameters to the click method. it just comes up with undefined for `view`, `event` and `ctx`

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Ember use the `actions` hash instead of methods directly on the object (though this deprecated method is still supported, it might not be for long). If you want a reference to the view passed to the handler, send through "view" as a parameter and use the `parentView` as the target.

```
<button {{action "onClicked" view target="view.parentView"}}>Click me.</button>

App.ListsView = Ember.View.extend({
    actions: {
        onClicked: function(view) {
        }
    }
});
```

`{{action}}` helper does not send through the event object. Still not sure how to get reference to the event if you need it.

[source](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/)