# Passing parameters in Ember's Custom Events (that bubble through the View hierarchy)?

Tags: ember.js

I couldn't find a way to pass arguments when using Ember's Custom Events which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918112/how-can-i-make-custom-events-that-bubble-through-the-view-hierarchy).
I prefer avoiding solutions which target "parent" views specifically, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379345/how-to-pass-events-to-a-parent-view-passing-the-child-view-that-triggered-the-e) since we lose the "bubbling".

My Usage is as following

plugins.js

> ```
> Em.Object.reopen({
>     triggerEvent: function (eventName) {
>         this.$().trigger(eventName, this);
>     }
> });
> ```

MyView.js

> click: function () {
>
> ```
>    this.triggerEvent('stepClicked');
> ```
>
> }

The code in Ember (0.96+) shows that passing an additional params is considered a manager, which isn't passed on

> ```
> rootElement.delegate('.ember-view', event + '.ember', function(evt, triggeringManager) {
>     ...
>     if (manager && manager !== triggeringManager) {
>           result = self._dispatchEvent(manager, evt, eventName, view);
>     } else if (view) {
>           result = self._bubbleEvent(view,evt,eventName);
>      }
> ```

Super thanks in advance,
Oren Rubin

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an event object which will tell you what element is being clicked on:

```
click: function(event){     
  // will be called when when an instance's     
  // rendered element is clicked
  console.log("element clicked: " + this.get('elementId') );
  return false; // return true if you want the click event to bubble up to parent view (default it true)
}
```

I think an even better way would be to use `{{action}}` in your template. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9381052/527559) for an example.